Simplifying time dilation formula
I am trying to simplify time dilation formula:
$\sqrt{(\frac{1}{2}cT_0)^2 + (\frac{1}{2}vT)^2} = \frac{1}{2}cT$
Which should lead into this:
$T = \frac{T_0}{\sqrt{1-(v^2/c^2)}}$
This is the process I went for, which did not work:
$\sqrt{(\frac{1}{2}cT_0)^2 + (\frac{1}{2}vT)^2} = \frac{1}{2}cT$
$(\frac{1}{2}cT_0)^2 + (\frac{1}{2}vT)^2 = \frac{1}{4}c^2T^2$
$\frac{1}{4}c^2T_0^2 + \frac{1}{4}v^2T^2 = \frac{1}{4}c^2T^2$
$\frac{1}{4}(c^2T_0^2 +v^2T^2) = \frac{1}{4}c^2T^2$
$c^2T_0^2 +v^2T^2 = c^2T^2$
$c^2T^2 -v^2T^2 =c^2T_0^2$
$T^2(c^2-v^2) =c^2T_0^2$
$T^2 = \frac {c^2T_0^2}{ (c^2-v^2)}$
$T= \frac {cT_0}{\sqrt{(c^2-v^2)}}$
Is this correct? How can I follow?

Divide both numerator and denominator by $c$, then take $1/c$ inside the radical. Or equivalent, in the next to last equation divide both numerator and denominator by $c^2$

That was great! For some reason I couldn't get to it! Thank you very much!

@Mayday I mean you say you couldn't get it but you were almost there and had exactly the right idea. You did great.
